# Cannot find other disk partitions after installing Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, files, windows-10, lts, ntfs-3g

My PC was running on Windows 10. There were 3 partitions on my hard disk. I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and removed Windows 10. But when I open Files application, I cant find any of the disk drives. I can see root directory only. NTFS 3G driver is already installed on my system. How can I find other drive and access my files

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu?  What option did you select when the installer asked you if you wanted to erase everything and install Ubuntu or install it alongside windows etc?

Comment: I selected the option 'Erase disk and install Ubuntu'.  Does it format my hard disk completely? @Stormlord

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you used the option to *Erase disk and install Ubuntu*, all your previous partitions got erased and the current one was created.

You can try installing and using `testdisk` and see what you can recover but I wouldn't be very optimistic unfortunately.

In cases where you need to keep some of your partitions, you must use the *Something else* option and handle partitioning manually.